# updating a df using an idxmax series from a different df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to update locations in a DataFrame based on an `idxmax` series from a different DataFrame. So for each row in `df0`, change the value of the column with the highest value in `df1` to 1. Is this possible without having to loop though each row?

Here's the code I'm trying to improve:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    '2020-05-04': [0, 0, 0],
    '2020-05-05': [0, 0, 0],
    '2020-05-06': [0, 0, 0]},
    orient='index', columns=['a','b','c'])

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    '2020-05-04': [1.1, 1.0, 1.0],
    '2020-05-05': [1.0, 1.2, 1.0],
    '2020-05-06': [1.0, 1.0, 1.4]},
    orient='index', columns=['a','b','c'])

for date in df0.index: 
    df0.loc[date, df1.idxmax(axis=1)[date]] = 1
```

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible using `unstack` and `fillna`:

```
# get 'coordinates' of max value
df0 = df1.idxmax(axis=1).rename('col').to_frame()

# set your 'marker' value
df0['val'] = 1

#             col  val
# 2020-05-04    a    1
# 2020-05-05    b    1
# 2020-05-06    c    1

df0 = df0.set_index('col', append=True).unstack().fillna(0)

#             val
# col           a    b    c
# 2020-05-04  1.0  0.0  0.0
# 2020-05-05  0.0  1.0  0.0
# 2020-05-06  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

The DataFrame now has a MultiIndex for columns. To drop the `val` level, run

```
df0.droplevel(0, axis=1)
```